# Calling constructor with braces instead parantheses

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list, delegating-constructor

I recently realized that in C++11 we can call a delegating initializer-list constructor like

```
Foo() : Foo{42} // delegate to Foo(initializer_list<>)
```

Is this syntax correct? It seems to be, although I would have expected to always use parentheses when calling a function, like `Foo({42})`. The example code below [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/xBPCPV) in both clang++ and g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() : Foo{42} // I would have expected invalid syntax, use Foo({42})
    {
        std::cout << "Foo()... delegating constructor\n";
    }
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int>)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo(initializer_list)\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

I am well aware of uniform initialization, like declaring *objects* using `{ }`, but did not know we can also call constructors. We **cannot** call functions though, the following [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/yAx4Yl):

```
#include <initializer_list>

void f(std::initializer_list<int>){}

int main()
{
    f{5}; // compile time error, must use f({5})
}
```

So, to summarize, my question is the following: are there special rules when delegating constructors, that allow for calling a init-list constructor using only braces, like `Foo{something}`?

Comment: You ask the most interesting questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a *mem-initializer* such as `Foo{42}` can contain either a parenthesized *expression-list* or a *braced-init-list*. This is the case regardless of whether the *mem-initializer-id* denotes the constructor's class, a base class, or a member: that is, both when the constructor delegates and when it does not. See the grammar in [class.base.init].

Furthermore, the standard specifies ([class.base.init]/7 in C++14) that the initialization by the *expression-list* or *braced-init-list* occurs according to the usual rules of initialization. Therefore if the initializer is a *braced-init-list* then `std::initializer_list` constructors will be favoured in overload resolution.

Answer (score 3):

I think the rule is pretty clear that you will be allowed to delegate to an initializer list constructor (emphasis mine):

> If the name of the class itself appears as class-or-identifier in the
>   member initializer list, then the list must consist of that one member
>   initializer only; such constructor is known as the delegating
>   constructor, and the constructor selected by the only member of the
>   initializer list is the target constructor In this case, **the target
>   constructor is selected by overload resolution** and executed first,
>   then the control returns to the delegating constructor and its body is
>   executed.

So by overload resolution, you can call your initializer list constructor just as if you were calling it in 'normal' code because.

However, I don't know of anything that should allow calling a function that accepts an initializer list in the same way that you can call a constructor with one.

Edit: [More](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) about constructor rules (Emphasis again mine):

> The body of a function definition of any constructor, before the
>   opening brace of the compound statement, may include the **member
>   initializer list, whose syntax is the colon character :**, followed by
>   the comma-separated list of one or more member-initializers, each of
>   which has the following syntax 
>         class-or-identifier (expression-list(optional) )   (1)  
>        **class-or-identifier brace-init-list   (2) (since C++11)** 
>         parameter-pack ... (3) (since C++11)
>
> 1) Initializes the base or member named by class-or-identifier using
>   direct initialization or, if expression-list is empty,
>   value-initialization 
>   2) **Initializes the base or member named by
>   class-or-identifier using list-initialization (which becomes
>   value-initialization if the list is empty and aggregate-initialization
>   when initializing an aggregate)** 
>   3) Initializes multiple bases using a
>   pack expansion

So according to #2, it appears it's legal.

Comment: I understand this, and I knew I can delegate to an init-list, however didn't know I can also call it like `Foo{...}` and not necessarily `Foo({...})`.